# What is the difference between Protocol and ProcessProtocol in Twisted python?

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, twisted.web

I wish to write a Twisted client application that can connect to a server through several sockets. I wish to use Factory, Protocol, Transport model because they appear to provide a good framework. Both [interfaces](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.0.0/twisted/internet/interfaces.py), Protocol and ProcessProtocol, inherit from BaseProtocol, but how are they different? Is ProcessProtocol a pool of Protocol? In particular, what is the child process in ProcessProtocol, and can this be used as a socket object?

```
IProtocol(Interface): 
dataReceived(data)
connectionLost(reason)
makeConnection(transport) 
connectionMade()

IProcessProtocol(Interface): 

childDataReceived(childFD, data)
childConnectionLost(childFD)
processExited(reason)
processEnded(reason)
```

Edit: found that ProcessProtocol may actually be launching python processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProcessProtocol is a protocol used to [communicate with a sub-process](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html). That process could be a Python process, or could be any other program you want to launch and communicate with by its standard-in, standard-out, and standard-error streams.